# (Routed) SQL injection on shared parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-injection

I am in charge of the security of several websites. Recently we bought the Acunetix WVS and performed several tests that gave positive on SQL injection. Not only am I trying to replicate these tests but I also trying to find out if it is possible to extract relevant information, given that we have a WAF/IPS deployed that mitigates the more critical SQL injections.

I am obviously not allowed to disclose the website I am currently testing on, for that I will refer to it as http://example.com.

I was able to find out that on the page http://example.com/show_results.php?group=1&query=members there are 2 queries being used to display the results. So maybe, this is related to Routed SQL Injection. I have applied several SQL injection techniques, and through the error messages I have identified that they take the form of:

```
SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE group='1' LIMIT 0,1

SELECT 1,2,3,4 FROM ... WHERE group='1' AND `user_type` NOT LIKE 'colaborators' ORDER BY 'name'
```

Both queries are displayed on individual `<div>`. `user_type` represents the `members` on the URL. The first query is obviously very easy to inject. I can get the database name by simply changing the URL to:

```
    http://example.com/show_results.php?group=1' union select database() -- - &query=
```

The obvious question here is: **How to get the table names** for instance. Something like:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=database()
```

This is tricky because both queries use the same `group` parameter, so it is not entirely Routed SQL Injection in its simplest form. Something like this:

```
    http://example.com/show_results.php?group=1' union select database() -- -&query=members
```

Note the difference brom above on the `query` parameter. This shows me the error of `The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns` (obviously because both queries have a different number of columns).

Comment: I don't understand what's the point in trying to devise a working exploit instead of fixing the vulnerability

Comment: Yes, filter the input properly, and use bindings.